Dirichlet Inverse Product Expansion for Non-Multiplicative Functions.
I was recently playing around with Dirichlet Inverses and found the following:
Let $f$ be an arithmetic function that is not multiplicative, and $f^{-1}$ denote it's Dirichlet Inverse.
Then for any prime $p$, and $n \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$,
$f^{-1}(p^n) = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n}} \Big(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_k(p) \Big)$,
where the term $R_k$ is a sort of nested linear fractional transformation of the following form:
$R_1(p) = 0$, $R_2(p) = \dfrac{\dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(1)}}{\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)}}$, $R_3(p) = \dfrac{ \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^3)}{f(p)}   }{\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(p)} }$, $R_4(p) = \dfrac{ \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{ \dfrac{f(p^3)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^4)}{f(p)}   }{\dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(p)} }  }{\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{ \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^3)}{f(p)}   }{\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} - \dfrac{f(p^2)}{f(p)} }}$
and so on...
The recursive relationship is made more clear in the proof of this, which I'll show here:
By https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-06/NNTDM-06-4-118-124.pdf, (2.5),
$f^{-1}(p^n) =  \dfrac{(-1)^n }{f(1)} \det(A)$,
where $A = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{f(p)}{f(1)} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \frac{f(p^2)}{f(1)} & \frac{f(p)}{f(1)} & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     \frac{f(p^{n-1} )}{f(1)} & \frac{f(p^{n-2} )}{f(1)} & \frac{f(p^{n-3} )}{f(1)} & \cdots & 1 \\
     \frac{f(p^{n} )}{f(1)}& \frac{f(p^{n-1} )}{f(1)}& \frac{f(p^{n-2} )}{f(1)}& \cdots & \frac{f(p )}{f(1)}
\end{pmatrix}_{\substack{n \times n}}$ .
We then define a new matrix $A^*$ that results from the following, recursive elementary row operations on A: $A^*_{n-i} := A_{n-i} - \dfrac{A^*_{n-i+1}}{a^*_{n-i+1, n-i+1}} $,
where $A^*_{n} = A_n$, starting from $i = 1$ to $i = n-1$.
The new matrix $A^*$ is lower triangular, with the diagonal entries of the form:  $\Big(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_k(p) \Big) $. And since $\det(A) = \det(A^*)$, and we have that $A^*$ is lower triangular, we get that  $f^{-1}(p^n) = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n}} \Big(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_k(p) \Big)$.
I've gone ahead and written some sympy code in colab so that it is easier to visualize this process: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cD-gOavH3aEhBJ_UOivo0LqEAVPpGxKs?usp=sharing .
The reason why this may be useful is that, written in this form, it lets us establish specific properties of the dirichlet inverse at prime powers for certain kinds of non multiplicative functions, that would otherwise be difficult to establish in my opinion.
For instance: if we have that $f(p)$ is monotonically decreasing in a sufficiently fast enough manner so that $f(p^{k+1}) = o(f(p^{k}))$ as $p \rightarrow \infty$, then we have that:
$|f^{-1}(p^n)| = \dfrac{1}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n}} \Big(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_k(p) \Big) =  \dfrac{1}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n}} \Theta\left(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} \right) = \Theta\Big( \dfrac{f^n(p)}{f^{n+1}(1)} \Big)  $ .
Furthermore, if we have this with the added property that $\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} < 1$, then we have that $|f^{-1}(p^{n+1})| <  |f^{-1}(p^{n})|$, since $|f^{-1}(p^{n+1})|$ is nothing but $|f^{-1}(p^{n})|$ multiplied by $\Big( \dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_{n+1}(p) \Big) < 1$. Furthermore, given the monotonic relationship, we would also have that $\text{sign}(f^{-1}(p^{n})) = (-1)^n$, since  $\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  R_{k}(p) > 0$, for all $k$.
My question:
Can we extend this and derive a similar product expansion to cover the Dirichlet inverse at non-prime powers?  Part of the inherent difficulty is that the determinant form for the dirichlet inverse at non-prime powers contains some zeros on the diagonals of the matrix in question, and hence such a gaussian elimination procedure there is not as straightforward. I have some code for that as well for those matrices if anyone would want me to post it. It is also shown in Theorem 2.1 of the paper linked.
Formally stated:
For any arithmetic function , we have that:
$f^{-1}(p^n) = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{n}} \Big(\dfrac{f(p)}{f(1)} -  \tilde{R_k}(p) \Big)$.
where $\tilde{R_k}(p)=  \begin{cases}
     R_k(p) , & \text{if } f \text{ is not multiplicative}\\
     0,& \text{if } f \text{ is multiplicative}\\
\end{cases}$.
So this can be viewed as a generalization of the product expansion for multiplicative function inverses at prime powers that accounts for non multiplicative functions as well.
So the intuition would be, for any number $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ with $\alpha_1 + ... + \alpha_r \geq 2$,  why shouldn't there be an analogous sequence $T_1( (p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r)), T_2((p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r)), \cdots, T_r((p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r)), \cdots$, such that:
$f^{-1}(n) = \dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(n)}}{f(1)} \displaystyle{\prod_{k=1}^{r}} \Big(\displaystyle{\prod_{j=1}^{\alpha_k}} \Big(\dfrac{f(p_k)}{f(1)} -  \tilde{R_j}(p_k) \Big) -  \tilde{T_k}((p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r)) \Big)$
where $\tilde{T_k}((p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r))=  \begin{cases}
     T_k((p_1, \alpha_1), ... (p_r, \alpha_r)) , & \text{if } f \text{ is not multiplicative}\\
     0,& \text{if } f \text{ is multiplicative}\\
\end{cases}$.
Does such a sequence exist? And if so, what would it look like? My guess would be if it does, it would involve some sort of recursive, continued linear fractional transformation like in the prime power case. Can we find such a sequence? If anyone has any thoughts, please let me know.

Have you looked up the relation between Dirichlet convolution and Dirichlet series?

Not really to be honest. I only know some of the surface level things like the product of two dirichlet series has coefficients which are the convolution of the coefficients of the two series. Was there anything in particular you were thinking of with regards to this?

The Dirichlet series of the Dirichlet inverse is exactly the reciprocal of the original function, so you can compute the values of the Dirichlet inverse by considering the Euler product.

Isn’t that just for multiplicative functions though? The purpose of this kind of approach is to be able to say something meaningful about functions that are not multiplicative.

I've added a comment in the post to make this distinction.

You can define an auxiliary $f^*(n)$ multiplicative function that agrees with $f(n)$ on prime powers.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
